# find xml attribute that have relationship child

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

Having an XML with FILE attributes that results linked together by child IN and OUT conditions element. Could be possible to obtain all the files "neighborhood" connected each-other, starting from single FILE name?
Because i'm trying the below code and if i search for 'D' FILE name, I've get the correct result but not if I search for 'A' FILE name

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all" expand-text="yes" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="find" as="xs:string*" select="'A'"/>

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:key name="Job-by-id" match="FILE" use="@NAME"/>

    <xsl:key name="outlink" match="FILE" use="IN/@NAME"/>


    <xsl:function name="mf:link-chain" as="element(FILE)*">
        <xsl:param name="job" as="element(FILE)"/>
        <xsl:sequence
            select="$job | key('outlink', $job/OUT[@SIGN = '+']/@NAME, root($job)) ! mf:link-chain(.)"/>

    </xsl:function>



    <xsl:key name="inlink" match="FILE" use="OUT[@SIGN = '+']/@NAME"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:link-chain-reverse" as="element(FILE)*">
        <xsl:param name="job" as="element(FILE)"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="$job | key('inlink', $job/IN/@NAME, root($job)) ! mf:link-chain-reverse(.)"/> 
    </xsl:function>


   <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
                <style xsl:expand-text="no">
                    table {
                    border-collapse: collapse;
                    }
                    tbody {
                    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                    }</style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DEFTABLE">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('Job-by-id', $find)"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FILE">
        <tbody>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="((mf:link-chain(.)/@NAME) | (mf:link-chain-reverse(.)/@NAME))"/>

        </tbody>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FILE/@NAME">
        <tr>
            <td>{.}</td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tested with following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<DEFTABLE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Folder.xsd">

  <FILE NAME="A">

      <OUT NAME="LINK01" SIGN="+" />
  </FILE>

  <FILE NAME="B">

      <OUT NAME="LINK01" SIGN="+" />
  </FILE>
  <FILE NAME="C">

      <IN NAME="LINK01" />
      <OUT NAME="LINK02" SIGN="+" />
  </FILE>
  <FILE NAME="D">

      <IN NAME="LINK02" />
      <IN NAME="LINK03" />
  </FILE>
  <FILE NAME="E">

      <OUT NAME="LINK03" SIGN="+" />
  </FILE>

</DEFTABLE>
```

Ressuming, for every eventually FILE name passed in search string, it will output list:
A-B-C-D-E

Kindly do you have any idea where is it wrong and how ca i fix it?

Comment: What would be the expected output? The code seems to create an HTML table, which table would you want to output for the `<xsl:param name="find" as="xs:string*" select="'A'"/>`?

Comment: I haven't quite understood the XML format but if you want to follow keys and you don't want to get a result in document order of the input document then I would suggest not to use the union operator `|` but the comma operator `,` instead as the union operator sorts its operands in document order. So perhaps https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEvp/2 helps although I am not sure it might not recurse endlessly for some inputs.

Comment: First, do note that you have a directed graph. Thus, it could branch and also have cycles. Then, as Martin almost said, the set union operator `|` will eliminate repetitions and `xsl:apply-templates` instruction will treat node-sets in document order.

Comment: Poposed solution is well suited to the example I had indicated. But as you rightly pointed out, i'm not able to manage the recurse endlessly and the remote branches for a huge XML.